# npm install fails with ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE on win11 host in ubruntu VirtualBox generic/ubuntu2204

Tags: virtualbox, npm

**Environment:**

- Win 11
- Vagrant box: VirtualBox generic/ubuntu2204
- "../gloss-translation" is repo root directory on host machine.

**Vagrantfile:**

```
  vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/~/gloss-translation", "1"]
  config.vm.synced_folder "../gloss-translation", "/home/vagrant/gloss-translation"

  # Root Provision section:
  config.vm.provision "shell", name: "nodejs", inline: <<-SHELL
    echo "Provisioning with root access"

    # Update resynchronizes the package index files from their sources. 
    apt-get update

    # *** Install Node.js 18 ***
    echo "Installing Node.js 18..."

    # 1. Download and import the Nodesource GPG key
    sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg
    sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg

    # 2. Create deb repository
    NODE_MAJOR=18
    echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

    # 3. Run Update and Install
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
    echo "End of: Installing Node.js 18"
  SHELL

  # Vagrant Provision section:
  config.vm.provision "shell", name: "npm", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL

    cd /home/vagrant/gloss-translation

    echo "Performing npm install..."
    npm install
    echo "Setting nx as global..."
    npm i -g nx
    echo "npm provisioning completed."
  SHELL
```

**Stdout Error Message:**

```
  vagrant@ubuntu2204:~/gloss-translation$ npm install
  npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
  npm ERR! syscall write
  npm ERR! errno -95
  npm ERR! ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, write
  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2023-10-03T14_08_28_991Z-debug-0.log
```

Excerpt of log file above:

```
56 timing command:install Completed in 170ms
57 verbose stack Error: ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, write
58 verbose cwd /home/vagrant/gloss-translation
59 verbose Linux 5.15.0-84-generic
60 verbose node v18.18.0
61 verbose npm  v9.8.1
62 error code ENOTSUP
63 error syscall write
64 error errno -95
65 error ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, write
66 verbose exit -95
67 timing npm Completed in 581ms
68 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1696342109381
69 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:save 1696342109541
70 verbose code -95
71 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2023-10-03T14_08_28_991Z-debug-0.log
```

**What I have tried to date:**

1. Ran this command: VBoxManage.exe setextradata vagrant-project_default_1696285759671_47273 VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/~/gloss-translation 1
2. Granted create symbolic links to "Authenticated Users" using Local Security Policy
3. Deleted directory "node_modules" in project root directory
4. Created a directory in the guest ~/node_modules;
   cd ~/gloss-translation; ln -s ~/node_modules; npm install

**Result:**
All of the above have failed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by changing this statement:

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "../gloss-translation", "/home/vagrant/gloss-translation"
```

with this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../gloss-translation", "/home/vagrant/gloss-translation", type: "rsync"
```

Only downside is that I need to issue:

```
vagrant rsync
```

in order to sync the folders or alternatively you can issue:

```
vagrant rsync-auto
```

to have vagrant monitor the directories and issue a rsync whenever they change.